# terminate while loop using character

Tags: c++, c++11

I need help with the following snippet:

Using `string in` the following loop *terminates:*

```
int main() {
string in;
while(1){
    cin >> in;
    if (in == "|")
        break;
}
```

But using `int in` the following loop *does not terminates:*

```
int main() {
int in;
while(1){
    cin >> in;
    if (in == '|')
        break;
    else 
        cout<< in << "\n";
}
```

I want to terminate the last shown snippet. Is it possible to do using `int in`.
I've seen the post [C++ Terminate loop using a char input to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652001/c-terminate-loop-using-a-char-input-to-int) but no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While characters are represented in the computer as small integers, an `int` is not the same as a `char`. Not in C++.

When you read into an `int` variable the `>>` operator tries to parse the input *as an integer*, as a number and not as a character.

If you want to read a character then *read* a character:

```
char in;
std::cin >> in;
```

---

If you try to read an integer, and the input is not a number, then the input operator will fail. See e.g. [this very simple example](http://ideone.com/9V5zJq).

Comment: It will do, but can you show me a way to terminate it while using `int in`.

Comment: @DeepChandra But you can't use `int` variables to read single characters using the formated `>>` operators. It's simply not possible. Then you need to use *two* variables: One `char` variable that you use to read the character, and another `int` variable assigned to the value of the `char` variable. Or use the unformatted [`std::istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) function (which might not work exactly as you expect depending on platform).

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I used

I needed to input integers to a vector as input using while loop indefinitely and terminate it using a character.
This approach takes the input as character and then convert this char into integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char in;
    std::vector<int> vec;
    while(1){
        cin>>in;
        if(in == '|'){
            break;
        }
        vec.push_back(in - '0');
    }
    
    for(int j=0; j<vec.size(); j++){
    cout<<vec[j];}
    
    return 0;
}
```